# How do I send an email that the password has been changed after password reset is done?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm using django 2.1 the default password reset according to documentation 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/

and I need after password reset is completed and the password is updated successfully to send the user an email that he has updated his password successfully How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

Sending email after password reset:

**settings.py:**

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@gmail.com' # mention email address from where you wanna send email.
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def password_reset(request):
   # code for password reset
   send_mail(
     'Password Reset',
     'Your password was changed.',
     'from@example.com',
     ['to@example.com'],
     fail_silently=False,
   )
   return render(request, 'myhtml.html')
```

for more info visit [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party app [djsoer](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser) to send email.